# Создание словаря ProGuard

Tags: windows

Необходимо создать словарь ProGuard вида

```
iiiiiiii
iiiiiiiI
iiiiiiII
iiiiiIII
IiIiIiIi
...
```

Словарь proguard - обычный текстовый файл. Строками как выше надо его заполнить, по одному слову на строку. Как я могу это сделать? Можно использовать любой язык программирования. При этом надо это сделать на windows, не linux.

Comment: А почему текстовой файл со строками называется вами словарем `ProGuard`, а не `ВжикУ` или `Операция Ы`? Это какой-то особый тип словаря? Из вашей иллюстрации не понятен принцип создания строк. Какая должна быть длина строки? Можно ли использовать другие буквы кроме  `i`. Принцип по которому происходит чередование заглавных и строковых.

Comment: Потому что я указал для чего этот файл будет предназначен. 8 символов длина строки должна быть. Принцип такой: есть всего одна буква: i ее нужно использовать в двух регистрах. И не только iiiiiiii и IIIIIIII а строки вида IiiiIIiI т.е. генерация строк с разным регистром. При этом они не должны повторятся. Можно перевести это например так: 00000000, потом должно создаться 00000001, 00000011, и так далее что бы перепробовать все различные комбинации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

рекурсия - наше "фсё"

Думаю, понятно, что VBscript-код  работает почти на всех платформах Windows (кроме ранних). Выводит полученный словарь в консоль (**cscript.exe //Nologo имя-скрипт-файла**).

```
Dim dic,l
dic = Array("I","i")
l = 8
writeIt 0,""

Sub writeIt(ll,string)
Dim i
  If ll < l Then
   For Each i In dic
    WriteIt ll+1,i & string
   Next
  Else
   Wscript.Echo string
   Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: А это на каком языке программирования?

Comment: VBscript ([WSH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host))